# How to assign a class on the $value within add_filter

Tags: php, wordpress, class, add-filter

I have this add_filter code.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', function ($items, $args) {
    $request_item = NULL;
    foreach ($items as $item ) {
        if ('/request/' == $item->url) 
            $request_item = $item;
    }

    if ($request_item) {
        if (ubitto_has_request_answer_permission()) {
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();

            global $wpdb;
            $count = $wpdb->get_var("select count(1) from {$wpdb->prefix}ub_request r inner join {$wpdb->prefix}posts p on r.topic_id = p.ID where r.end_date is null and
                (r.coupon_id is null or exists(select 1 from {$wpdb->prefix}ub_coupon c where c.id = r.coupon_id and c.type = 'request' and c.author_id = {$user_id}))");
            $request_item->title = "Learners' requests - $count";

        } else {
            $request_item->title = "My requests";
        }
    }

    return $items;
}, 10, 2);
```

I hope to apply a class='count' on the value of $count above...

[[image]

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?
I have super basic code understanding.

I already have the css ready

Thank you

Comment: Well for starters, you'll need that `115` to be in a separate HTML element, if you want to be able to format it separately. But just setting the title as `Learners' requests <span>$count</span>` likely won't work, I am guessing the Walker_Nav_Menu instance used to output this menu will probably apply HTML escaping. So you might need to create your own custom class based on `Walker_Nav_Menu`, to create the output in the specific way you need.

Comment: What a simple solution!! How I wish I have learnt php before.. Yes, it fixed like this!
<span class='count'>$count</span>

Thank you for the quick guidance!